# Mapping a List using a Custom Resolver with Automapper

Tags: c#, collections, mapping, automapper

I have 2 objects that I need to map to each other. They look like

```
public class Example1
{
     CustomType1 Prop { get; set; }
     List<CustomType1> List { get; set; } 
}

public class Example2
{
    Customtype2 Prop { get; set; }
    List<Customtype2> List { get; set; } 
}

public class CustomType1
{
    public string SomeString { get; set; }
}

public class Customtype2
{
    public string FirstPartOfSomeString { get; set; }

    public string SecondPartOfSomeString { get; set; }
}
```

I want to make one CustomResolver that maps CustomType1 to CustomType2 and then use that resolver on the list. For example,

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Example1, Example2>()
            .ForMember(d => d.Prop, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(myCustomResolver))
            .ForMember(d => d.List, opt => opt.ResolveUsing( /*use myCustomResolver on a list here*/));
```

I have tried using something like:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Example1, Example2>()
            .ForMember(d => d.Prop, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(myCustomResolver))
            .ForMember(d => d.List, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.List.Select(myCustomResolver.Resolve).ToList()));
```

but I seem to be missing something. Is there a way to do this with AutoMapper?

Comment: Please post the CustomResolver code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding a mapping between the custom types instead of using a resolver?
AutoMapper is intelligent enough to re-use mappings for lists...

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CustomType1, CustomType2>()
    .ForMember(x => FirstPartOfSomeString, opts => opts.MapFrom(x => x.SomeString.Substring(5)))
    .ForMember(x => SecondPartOfSomeString, opts => opts.MapFrom(x => x.SomeString.Substring(5, 5)));

Mapper.CreateMap<Example1, Example2>();
```

Comment: This worked. If you define the CustomType1 to CustomType2 map prior  to mapping the collections, then you can reuse the mapping with the list. Thanks.